# Automatic variable name generation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not very experienced in python and I need some help.
I would like to generate names for some variables automatically, but i don't know how to. Let's say, i have a dict with 20 values and i want to generate 20 names for the 20 values.

I tried this way, but obviously, python can not assign a string to an item

```
    for i in range(len(dict)):
       name[i] = 'var_{}'.format(i)
       self.name[i] = dict[i]
```

The result should look like :

```
   self.var_0 = content of dict[0]
   self.var_1 = content of dict[1]
   .
   .
   .
   self.var_31 = content of dict[31]
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Is `dict` actually a dict? Are the keys actually `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`? Are you just trying be able to access the dict using attribute lookups on an instance of a class you're building?

Comment: Yes it's a bit difficult to explain in fact. But i want to cast the values of a dictionary to a number of variables which names terminate with a number. The number correspond to the index i. My dict doesn't have a fixed length and i don't know what are the types of the keys at first. It can be number or whatever, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) function.

> `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    setattr(self, f'var_{key}', value)
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is what i am looking for. I will try this tomorrow, i am done for today.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I hope this is what you need.

```
dict_source={1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}
name=[]
dict_final={}
for i in range(1,4):
    var_name='var_{}'.format(i)
    name.append(var_name)
    dict_final[name[i-1]]=dict_source[i]
```